# Physics.Raycast hits default layer always

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to do a raycast on my layer called "Solid Terrain" this does not work as it always takes the default layer into consideration.

```
var iSolidTerrain = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Solid Terrain");
Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, 1000, iSolidTerrain);
```

Executing this will also hit against default layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation of unity it tells us that the third parameter of the "Physics.Raycast" is actually a bit mask so we could explicitly ignore the "Default" layer and filter out the "Solid Terrain" layer by doing the following:

```
var iDefault = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Default");
var iSolidTerrain = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Solid Terrain");
Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, 1000, 1<<iSolidTerrain|0<<iDefault)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, [`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) takes a layer mask, instead of a layer. If you want to reference the layer by its name, you should use [`LayerMask.GetMask`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.GetMask.html) to achieve that:

```cs
int mask = LayerMask.GetMask("Solid Terrain");
Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, 1000, mask);
```